# UINavigationBar is under StatusBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm developing a tiny app. And I'm having a problem I can't solve. I'm pushing a viewController to a navigationController and this screenshot is showing what's happening.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the code I'm using:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init] ;
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

TestViewController *testViewController =[[TestViewController alloc] init];
[navController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];
```

It's driving me crazy, I been gogling for an hour without success, any idea how to fix this?

---

### Update

Is something related with the statusbar. If I change in the info.plist file the "Status Bar is initially hidden" to "NO", then the app works fine but the status bar is shown in the launch screen. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did is positioning the UINavigationBar manually. I hope it helps someone else!

Comment: You should't have to do that... are you using Storyboard?

Answer (score 4):

Try initializing your nav controller differently

```
  TestViewController *testViewController =[[TestViewController alloc] init];
  self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:testViewController];
  [self.window setRootViewController:self.navController];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And for sake of all saints use capital letters for class names.

Comment: I still have the misplaced UINavigabtionBar... I don't know what else to try... thanks for your help anyway